# Uninterruptible Power Supply Unit Failure, Or Is It the Battery?

Tags: power-supply, battery, power, ups

I have an APC brand, SUA750 Model UPS unit that has been in service since late 2008. Recently, it failed completely when there was no power outage. (If any power outage occurred, it was for only a small fraction of a second.)

The unit interrupted the power supply to my PC equipment momentarily, then restored power again, but the "replace battery" light came on.

The problem is, the battery in the unit is less than 2 years old and is a genuine APC brand battery purchased directly from APC. It has been passing the "check battery" test with no problem every 2 weeks since it's been installed.

How could it be that, all of the sudden, the battery can't even supply backup power for even a fraction of a second, when it's been passing the "check battery" test every time? (The load on the UPS unit is only at 20% of it's capacity.)

I power-cycled the unit and ran the self test, but the "replace battery" light remains on.

Could it be that something is wrong with my UPS unit? I only ask this because it seems strange that, in less than 2 weeks time, the battery went from being able to power my PC equipment for 8-10 seconds during the regularly scheduled battery test to not even being able to power it for a fraction of a second... Perhaps the UPS unit itself is malfunctioning?

Comment: 8-10 seconds? or 8-10 minutes?  Was it all working fully ok a few days after replacing the batteries? Did you re-check the wiring, strong stable connections and any external disconnect to be very well connected (high amps)?  Do you have a voltmeter , seperate charger you can use temporarily?  Did you ever purposfully cycle them?

Comment: When I say 8-10 seconds, I mean that's the length of the battery test that the unit runs every 2 weeks to determine if the health of the battery is still good. -- Everything has been working fully OK ever since replacing the battery about 1.5 years ago. -- Not sure what is meant by "the wiring, strong stable connections and any external disconnect", but everything is plugged in securely to the unit. -- I have no voltmeter or separate charger to test the battery, unfortunately. -- I don't recall ever purposely cycling this battery, but it has been close to drained at least once, not completely.

Comment: If "the wiring, strong stable connections and any external disconnect" refers to the actual connections of the battery to the UPS inside of the unit, then I haven't checked that since the battery was installed, but I can say for sure that it was plugged in very securely.

Comment: and when it got close to drained on your ~20% load it ran for at least 10-15 minutes?  If somehow you could get hold of a voltmeter that would tell you a lot without much effort. if the charge curcuit stuff is working any set of 12V batts should show >13v about 13.4-13.9 when charged.  That would indicate if the charge curcuit is ok. .  When in use (even at your 20%) they should not drop below 11 at first, the more drop the more weak they are. Any "bad cell" charged or not will knock all that back the ~2v that a "cell" is. Comparing any team of batteries with just voltage would spot a bad one.

Comment: It ran for about 7 min before I manually shut the PC down, and there was still 30% batt. charge left. This was about 1 year ago. -- On Amazon.com, I'm going to buy the "Mini Digital Voltmeter Tester Voltage Meter 12v 24v Volt Gauge by DROK". I'll try to test the battery with that when it arrives. --  How many years does a new APC UPS unit generally last?

Comment: the unit itself a person would expect to last 10-15 years (but it won't), until the capacitors are cycled to the point of not so good anymore.  Batteries about 2-4y. I found some batts that are much stonger for the purpose of huge loads, the HR series (only) of B.B.batteries, is more like the right batts for that job when using lead-acid.

Comment: Psycogeek, thanks for your answers to my questions, they have been helpful. I don't have the rep to upvote them yet, unfortunately.